# C# User Control custom Properties

Tags: c#, user-controls, custom-controls

I am creating a user control and would like to create a custom menu like this
http://i56.tinypic.com/5ycaqb.png but I do not know what to do, can you help me? (Sorry for my bad English)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to look into [DesignerActionList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designeractionlist.aspx).

Specifically in your ControlDesigner (or the one that you have that extends from it), you'll need to override

```
public virtual DesignerActionListCollection ActionLists { get; }
```